# Confusion regarding friction in multi-object system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

I am confused from the books answer to this question, and confident about my approach of firstly using a combined system to find the acceleration of both objects, then using that acceleration to find the force exerted on the trailer by the car using Newton’s second law.
Please guide me and let me know where I’m going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

[[image: my attempt]
[image: books solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assumed that the coefficient of friction for the car is the same as that give for the trailer (0.15) so the frictional force acting on the car and the trailer is

$1630 \times 9.8 \times 0.15 = 2396.1$ Newtons

You have also assumed that friction acts in a backwards direction on the car.

But you are *told* that the force exerted by the car on the ground is $3600$ N. By Newton's Third Law, this is equal and opposite to the frictional force exerted by the ground on the car. Also, note that friction acts in a forwards direction on the car (this is what drives the car forwards) but in a backwards direction on the trailer. So the net frictional force acting on the car and the trailer is in fact

$3600 - 350 \times 9.8 \times 0.15 = 3085.5$ Newtons

in a forwards direction. The forwards acceleration of the car and the trailer is therefore

$\displaystyle \frac {3085.5} {1630} = 1.893$ m/s$^2$

which is the value given in the textbook answer.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for your help

Comment: can you further clarify why would the frictional force on the car act in the direction of the car? Assume the car is moving forward, wouldn’t friction be in the opposite direction retarding the motion? In effect, wouldn’t the force exerted by the car on the ground = friction force such that they oppose the motion of the car? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DoePual The car pushes backwards on the ground and the ground pushes forwards on the car - this is due to friction, and it is what moves the car forward. If there were no friction between the car and the ground the car's tyres would just spin and the car could not move forward at all.